# How do I access `this` from JavaScript via JS - Dart interop?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I need to access a JavaScript object's `this` from a Dart function. I'm effectively adding a new method to a JavaScript object, via Dart-JS interop. I need to access properties that are on the JavaScript object from the method defined in Dart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Callback` constructor can pass the `this` from JavaScript. According to the [API docs for Callback](http://dart-lang.github.io/js-interop/docs/js/Callback.html):

```dart
new Callback.many(Function f, {bool withThis: false})
new Callback.once(Function f, {bool withThis: false})
```

Here is an example:

Dart code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

void main() {
  var greeter = js.context['greeter'];
  var msg = greeter['greet']('Bob');
  greeter['doCoolStuff'] = new js.Callback.many(doCoolStuff, withThis: true);
}

doCoolStuff(jsThis) {
  print(jsThis['msg']);
}
```

Notice the use of `withThis: true` when creating the Callback. The `this` from JavaScript is passed in as the first argument to the callback function. In this case, I give it a name of `jsThis`.

JavaScript code:

```js
function Greeter() {
  this.msg = 'hello';

  var that = this;
  document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
    that.doCoolStuff();
  });
}

Greeter.prototype.greet = function(name) {
  return this.msg + ' ' + name;
}

var greeter = new Greeter();

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function() {
  greeter.doCoolStuff(); // comes from Dart land
});
```